# Modal con botones de acción y JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

tengo una duda ya que no soy experto en javascript, estoy usando datatables.

Mi problema es este, si hago la peticion con este boton:

```
<button data-id='.$row["userid"].' id='.$row["userid"].' title="Modificar Datos de Usuario" class="userinfo btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button>
```

me ejecuta este script que envía el id a una pagina con ajax y luego devuelve todo a la ventana modal

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.userinfo').click(function(){
   var userid = $(this).data('id');
   // AJAX request
   $.ajax({
    url: 'page1.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {userid: userid},
    success: function(response){ 
      // Add response in Modal body
      $('.modal-content').html(response);
      // Display Modal
      $('#empModal').modal('show'); 
    }
  });
 });
});

  </script>
```

Luego todo se carga en esta ventana modal

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" style="overflow-y: scroll;" id="empModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl"  >
    <div class="modal-content" >
  
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fas fa-times"></span> Cerrar Ventana</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

El problema es que si quiero poner un segundo boton que me ejecute una accion diferente en otra pagina diferente "page2.php", no logro que haga la peticion a page2.php y siempre me ejecuta la pagina page1.php.

El segundo botón lo tengo así:

```
<button data-id2='.$row["username"].' id2='.$row["username"].' title="Modificar Datos de Usuario" class="userinfo btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button>
```

y ese boton ejecuta esta accion:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.userinfo2').click(function(){
   var userid2 = $(this).data('id2');
   // AJAX request
   $.ajax({
    url: 'page2.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {userid2: userid2},
    success: function(response){ 
      // Add response in Modal body
      $('.modal-content').html(response);
      // Display Modal
      $('#empModal').modal('show'); 
    }
  });
 });
});
  </script>
```

El problema es que abre el modal pero no recibe los datos de mi segundo boton, estoy seguro que es por el javascript.

Si alguien me puede dar luces por favor de que tengo mal, se los agradezco

olvide comentar que en el archivo page1.php recibo la info así:

```
$userid = 0;
if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['userid']);
```

y en page2.php recibo la info asi:

```
$userid2 = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['userid2'])){
    $userid2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['userid2']);
```

Gracias

Comment: por que en el primer botón tienes id='.$row["userid"].' y en el segundo id2='.$row["username"].' en uno le mandas el id y en el otro el nombre?

Comment: En el segundo botón no estás especificando correctamente la clase: `class="userinfo btn btn-primary btn-sm"`, debería ser `class="userinfo2 btn btn-primary btn-sm"`

Comment: Tienes razón, no estaba especificando esa clase y por eso no hacia el envio de forma correcta, gracias